# swap one female name in-between two male name

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to swap one female name in between two male names

Input

```
Id   Name  Sal   Gender
1     AA   2000   M
2     BB   1500   M
3     CC   3000   F
```

expected output could be

```
Id   Name  Sal   Gender
1     AA   2000   M
3     CC   3000   F
2     BB   1500   M
```

Comment: Do you want interleaving rows?

Comment: as  table is by nature unsorted and id usually are connected to other tables, it is very unwise to change the ID even when the don't autoincrement

Comment: No sorry my mistake id should also change with other column fields

Answer (score 1):

One option is to split people by gender, fetching `rownum` for each of them so that later sorting returns desired output.

With sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME         SAL GENDER
---------- ----- ---------- ----------
         1 AA          2000 M
         2 BB          1500 M
         3 CC          3000 F
```

Query:

```
SQL> with temp as(
  2    select t.*, rownum rn
  3    from test t
  4    where gender = 'M'
  5    union
  6    select t.*, rownum rn
  7    from test t
  8    where gender = 'F'
  9  )
 10  select row_number() over (order by rn) id,
 11    name, sal, gender
 12  from temp
 13  order by rn, gender;

        ID NAME         SAL GENDER
---------- ----- ---------- ----------
         1 AA          2000 M
         2 CC          3000 F
         3 BB          1500 M

SQL>
```

Comment: nice solution, but line 13 should order by rn, gender.
Otherwise for every pair of rows having the same rn, the order of appearance is undeterministic, so it could result in a sequence like M-F-F-M

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you, @dami, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT ID, A_NAME, SAL, GENDER
FROM    ( Select 
              ID, A_NAME, SAL, GENDER, ROWNUM "RN", ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By GENDER Order By ID) "GENDER_RN" 
          From tbl
          Order By ID
        )
Order By GENDER_RN, RN
```

... with your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        ( Select 1 ID, 'AA' "A_NAME", 2000 "SAL", 'M' "GENDER" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 ID, 'BB' "A_NAME", 1500 "SAL", 'M' "GENDER" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 ID, 'CC' "A_NAME", 3000 "SAL", 'F' "GENDER" From Dual 
        )
```

... it results with:

```sql
        ID A_NAME        SAL GENDER
---------- ------ ---------- ------
         1 AA           2000 M      
         3 CC           3000 F      
         2 BB           1500 M
```

And if you have some more rows like here:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        ( Select 1 ID, 'AA' "A_NAME", 2000 "SAL", 'M' "GENDER" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 ID, 'BB' "A_NAME", 1500 "SAL", 'M' "GENDER" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 ID, 'CC' "A_NAME", 3000 "SAL", 'F' "GENDER" From Dual Union All
          --
          Select 4 ID, 'DD' "A_NAME", 1800 "SAL", 'F' "GENDER" From Dual Union All
          Select 5 ID, 'EE' "A_NAME", 2100 "SAL", 'M' "GENDER" From Dual Union All
          Select 6 ID, 'FF' "A_NAME", 2700 "SAL", 'F' "GENDER" From Dual )
```

... the result is:

```sql
        ID A_NAME        SAL GENDER
---------- ------ ---------- ------
         1 AA           2000 M      
         3 CC           3000 F      
         2 BB           1500 M      
         4 DD           1800 F      
         5 EE           2100 M      
         6 FF           2700 F
```

To reverse the order from M F M F into F M F M use DESC on RN in Order By clause...